# Using instance_of parameter matcher in mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, ruby-mocha

I want to use a `instance_of` parameter matcher for a test in `ActionController::TestCase`. I have imported the following files

```
require 'mocha/api'
require 'mocha/setup'
```

I wish to write something like this.

```
Book.any_instance.stubs(:read).with(instance_of(String)).returns true
```

But I get a message no method error for `instance_of`. Although I am able to use it in another file where it is configured for RSpec.
Could you please let me know the required files I need to import to use the parameter matchers

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/freerange/mocha#rspec says we should use `config.mock_with :mocha` in RSpec config where you find working.

Let's dive into the code on GitHub. The code for `mock_with` is found [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/3-9-maintenance/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L754-L784).

It seems it requires another file and it's [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/3-9-maintenance/lib/rspec/core/mocking_adapters/mocha.rb).

You can check the code above and will see that you need to require mocha like this:

```rb
begin
  require 'mocha/api'

  begin
    require 'mocha/object'
  rescue LoadError
    # Mocha >= 0.13.0 no longer contains this file nor needs it to be loaded.
  end
rescue LoadError
  require 'mocha/standalone'
  require 'mocha/object'
end
```

Note that you need not to require exactly like this. When you know the version of mocha you use, you can require required components only.